# Zero R algorithm and confusion matrix for equal distributed target variable

Tags: confusion-matrix

So I am facing a multinomial classification problem with 3 classes in the target variable.

Each of these 3 classes has exactly 369 instances, now I know the zero-rule algorithm predicts the majority class in the target variable.
However, how does it work if all classes are equal?

I have run the algorithm getting this confusion matrix:

[image]

Can anybody tell me how this confusion matrix is obtained.
That as of my understanding it would classify all instances in 1 column?